# javascript in CK Editor

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, ckeditor

I created a web form in .net. The form need to use WYSIWYG editor. So, I have decided to use [CK editor](http://ckeditor.com/). Now, I have gotten a problem that the CK editor lets to use javascript in the textarea. I don't want to let this. How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this post:

http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=18911&hilit=allowed+tags

That plugin sounds like what you'll need - something to clean out Javascript.